# ethernet connection to multiple devices

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet

I have an ethernet outlet in my games room I move the ethernet from device as I want to use them is it possible to connect a switch and plug my Mac and two games consoles in or do I have to go direct to the router with one of the switches ports?? I'm a complete noob so don't want to waste money if I don't have to. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an active Ethernet outlet in your games room (test it with a laptop computer and an Ethernet wire), then you need only add a small switch at that outlet and connect your devices by Ethernet. No need to go back to the router.

If you wish Wireless Devices in here, you can add a Wireless Router to the switch later.

If you wish Wireless now, get a small wireless router for this area. Connect as follows:

1. Hook a LAN port on the wireless router to the Ethernet connection on the wall.
2. Give the Wireless router a static IP address on your main network.
3. Turn DHCP OFF on the wireless router.

Now the wireless router is an extension of your main network.

Get a wireless router that includes Ethernet ports (common) and you can attach your consoles to that.

So switch or router, they will both work. The router provides flexibility down the road if you need it.

Comment: I have my Mac plugged in and my consoles are wireless but I want it all to we wired so I thought a 5 port switch but wanted to make sure it would work and I didn't have to run a cable directly from the router

Comment: It will all work and I amended my answer to include the option of wireless now so as to save purchasing an extra device down the road.